# Return smallest even number from 3 arguments or largest uneven number if there are no even numbers

Tags: haskell

I have a semi-voluntary Haskell homework here and need some help on how to solve it. 
The task:

Write a Haskell function

```
evenmin a b c
```

that returns the smallest even number from the arguments or the largest uneven one if there is no even number in the arguments.

I know that i can do that with many guards, but I am sure that there is a much nicer way! Please don't write out solution, but nudge me in the right direction if you can. Thanks!

Comment: Write out what you've got, and post it to the code review stackexchange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Instead of 3 arguments, suppose your input is a non-empty list of integers, i.e.

```
evenmin' :: [Int] -> Int
```

Suppose further you have a function `phi` that *partitions* the input like so:

```
phi [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] == ([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
```

What would the definition of `evenmin'` be? Afterwards, define `evenmin a b c = evenmin' [a, b, c]`.

Comment: `sep :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])`  

`sep list =`  

`([a|a<-list, mod a 2 == 0], [b|b<-list, mod b 2 == 1])`  
`evenmin' :: [Int] -> Int`  
`evenmin' list | fst (sep list) == [] = maximum (snd(sep list))`  
    `| otherwise = minimum (fst(sep list))`

`my_evenmin :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`  
  
`my_evenmin a b c = evenmin' [a, b, c]`
so sorry i cannot figure out this markdown thing in 5 allowed minutes. Thank you very much for your help!
Btw, do line breaks work with two spaces? I am unable to break a line...

Comment: @user226447 I'm not sure line breaks work in comments. By the way, now that you've done your homework you may find http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:partition useful next time.

Comment: K00l, thank you. I think it wouldn't be wrong to let Haskell do my work but it would be very lazy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Order integers in this way:

- even integers are ordered by `<=`
- odd integers are ordered by `>=`
- even integers are always smaller than odd ones.

Define `myCompare :: Int -> Int -> Ordering`.

Realize you want the minimum according to the above ordering.

How to compute the minimum of two objects w.r.t. a generic ordering?

How to extend that to three objects?

Bonus: how to extend that to lists?